# How to get all full paths to all child elements

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, data-structures, tree

Given a tree based of list of lists:

```py
tree = [
  "A",
  [
    "B1",
    [
      "C"
    ]
  ],
  [
    "B2",
    [
      "C",
      [
        "D1",
        [
          "E1"
        ],
        [
          "E2"
        ]
      ],
      [
        "D2"
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

I want to get the full path to all child elements as concatenated string in a list.

```py
result = [
  'A>B1>C',
  'A>B2>C>D1>E1',
  'A>B2>C>D1>E2',
  'A>B2>C>D2'
]
```

The delimiter `>` is changeable.

I tried different things with recursion and yield. But my head is burning.

Comment: can you add what you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this it works.

```
def leave_paths(current):
    if len(current) == 1:
        return [current]
    # Take all branches, get the paths for the branch, and prepend
    return [[current[0]] + path for branch in current[1:] for path in leave_paths(branch)]

output = ['>'.join(sub_list) for sub_list in leave_paths(s)]
print(output)
```

Output

`['A>B1>C', 'A>B2>C>D1>E1', 'A>B2>C>D1>E2', 'A>B2>C>D2']`

Answer (score 0):

Smth like this

```
def findLeaves(tree):
   name=tree[0]
   If len(tree)==1:
      return [name]
   else:
      return [name+"->"+path for branch in tree[1:] for path in findLeaves(branch)]
```